# Directives using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-directive

We have 3 tabs in my application and need to validate these using angularjs.Most of the fields in each tab are repeated like first name,last name,email,zip,mobile no and SSN etc.

1)What is best practice to validate fields using angularjs.Should I use ng-pattern in the input tag or should I go for custom directives for all  the fields

//using ng-pattern

```
<input type="number" name="SSN" ng-pattern="ssnregurlarexpressionpattern">
```

or

//using custom directives

```
<input type="number" name="SSN"   ssndirective">
```

Comment: you want to limit your input to only for numbers?

Comment: @Seminda,Can you elaborate what do you mean?

Comment: when user try to enter vlue to your input, user can only enter numbers. not allow to enter any other characters. thats what I mean

Comment: @Seminda user can enter any number or character and once he leaves text box need to validate